# MySQL join slow even after indexing

Tags: mysql, performance, left-join

I have two tables members and dep whose description are as follows:

```
TABLE members:
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| MemberID_M      | varchar(8) | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| Age             | varchar(5) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| Sex             | varchar(1) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| SomeInfo        | int(11)    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
TABLE dep:
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type       | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| MemberID_t      | int(11)    | YES  | MUL | NULL    |       |
| YEAR            | varchar(2) | NO   |     |         |       |
| Days            | tinyint(4) | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| train           | bigint(20) | NO   |     | 0       |       |
+-----------------+------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I want to perform the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 
SELECT a.*,b.* 
FROM dep AS a LEFT OUTER JOIN members AS b 
          ON  a.MemberID_t = b.Memberid_M;
```

Intially, the ids in both the tables were not indexed and the query did not return for hours. Now, even after indexing it is taking a lot of time.

```
EXPLAIN for the SELECT part of the query is:
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 436689 |       |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | memid2        | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 226127 |       |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------+
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is  MemberID_M  is a varchar and MemberID_t is an INT

The conversion of this fields is why take so long

For optimal results, the key fields has to be the same type

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked. I was looking at other optimizations and overlooked this.

Comment: AWESOME. Down from 4 seconds to about 0.0022 secs! How cool is that?

Answer (score 2):

You are joining based on columns which are not of the same type. One is an INT while the other a VARCHAR. This is probably causing a large amount of time to be spent on conversions (not certain also if MySQL will ignore the keys based on this also).

Further minor point, is it logical to have NULL values in what appear to be your primary keys?

Comment: Thanks @Kickstart! They are not primary keys.